# Ассемблер MASM не видит функции из "Windows API"-ских библиотек

Tags: windows, ассемблер, библиотеки, masm, messagebox

Изучаю Ассемблер для архитектур x86 Intel-овских процессоров на Windows. Новичок.

Ассемблер MASM не видит функции из "Windows API"-ских библиотек. Вот весь мой код "Hello world"-а через MessageBox. ("`.inc`"-файлы и прочее использовать не хочу, хочу в деталях самим расписывать и без них делать. Использую **не** MASM32 из сайта [masm32.com](https://www.masm32.com/), а `ml.exe` из папки Visual Studio (использую Visual Studio 2019 года. У самого́ Windows 7)).

```
; Код на MASM

.386    ; Указывается процессор с минимальным набором функций (так как новые процессоры Intel (в семействе архитектур "x86") совместимы (пока что) с инструкциями старых процессоров Intel того же семейства архитектур)

option      casemap:none    ; Насколько я понял, функции из Windows API без чувствительности к регистру не работают

; **** Импорт того что нужно ****

includelib  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib"   ; Загружаю главную статическую библиотеку без которой (насколько я понял) не заработает ни одна Windows-программа (то есть неконсольная)

extern      LoadLibraryA:near     ; Загружаю из статических библиотек используемые в этой программе функции (не знаю near использовать или far, но буду использовать near, так как читал что библиотеки (статические и динамические) загружаются прямо в пространство памяти самой программы)
extern      GetProcAddress:near   ; ^
extern      FreeLibrary:near      ; ^
extern      ExitProcess:near      ; ^

; **** Объявление сегментов памяти ****

.model flat     ; Директива, без которой, походу, 32-битное приложение не напишешь

.data

        header                  db  'Title of hello world', 0   ; Заголовок "Text Box"-овского окна
        text                    db  'Hello world', 0            ; Текст в "Text Box"-овском окне

        nameOfDLL               db  'user32.dll', 0             ; Здесь хранится имя подключаемой DLL библиотеки
        nameOfProcedureOfDLL    db  'MessageBoxA', 0            ; Здесь хранится имя подключаемой процедуры

        handlerToModule         dd  0
        addressOfProcedureOfDLL dd  0                           ; Зарезервировал для передачи сюда (на хранение) адреса DLL-овской функции

.code

; **** Точка входа в программу ****

_StartOfProgram:    ; Ассемблер MASM почему-то рекомендует ставить знак "_" перед меткой точки входа в программу

        push    offset nameOfDLL
        call    LoadLibraryA             ; Динамически подключаю DLL чтобы потом взять из неё функцию
        
        mov     handlerToModule, eax
        
        push    offset nameOfProcedureOfDLL
        push    eax                         ; Функции из Windows API используют соглашение stdcall. stdcall - это соглашение о передаче параметров функции в стэк задом наперёд, поэтому eax последним. В eax пока что содержится адрес DLL, поэтому лучше использовать регистр, процессор быстрее работает с регистрами
        call    GetProcAddress

        mov     addressOfProcedureOfDLL, eax   ; Сохраняю адрес процедуры MessageBox (чтоб тыщу раз потом не вызывать GetProcAddress)

        push    0
        push    offset text
        push    offset header
        push    0
        call    eax                     ; В eax адрес функции MessageBoxA. То есть вызываю эту функцию. Так как вместо регистров(то есть в данном случае eax) подставляется не адрес(как у меток), а само значение, то есть, в данном случае, адрес функции

        push    0
        call    ExitProcess

end _StartOfProgram
```

А консоль выдаёт вот что:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x86\ml.exe" "C:\Assembler\Main.asm" /link /subsystem:windows
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.29.30138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: C:\Assembler\Main.asm
C:\Assembler\Main.asm(43) : error A2006:undefined symbol : LoadLibraryA
C:\Assembler\Main.asm(46) : error A2006:undefined symbol : ExitProcess
C:\Assembler\Main.asm(50) : error A2006:undefined symbol : GetProcAddress
C:\Assembler\Main.asm(61) : error A2006:undefined symbol : ExitProcess
```

Не понимаю как это решить, чтобы MASM видел что эти функции (`LoadLibraryA`, и т.д.) находятся в "`kernel32.dll`" (на которую в теории должна указывать "`kernel32.lib`" подключенная с помощью директивы "`includelib`")

Comment: includelib не достаточно, нужны еще include с объявлением этих функций (что-то типа `include kernel32.inc`)

Comment: @insolor, я их уже объявил как раз с помощью директивы extern. И, как я уже сказал выше, мне не хочется использовать ".inc" файлы, так как хочется самим всё это объявлять и видеть, чтобы всё контролировать и каких-то скрытых вещей от меня не было, ведь файлы ".inc" как раз и содержат все эти объявления и делаются некоторыми для удобства

Comment: Ну так-то и в lib файле могут быть какие-то скрытые вещи, вообще там может быть какой-то код, который прилинкуется к exe, но никак не будет использоваться.

Comment: @insolor, файлы ".lib" являются бинарными. То есть уже переведёнными в машинный код. Поэтому их не получится считать, по крайней мере пока что (я таких программ не знаю). Поэтому как-то их раскрыть и прочитать (или обойтись без них) в Windows API (а точнее работая с Windows API) не получится. По крайней мере пока-что Microsoft не дала такой возможности

Comment: @insolor, сейчас нашёл одну [программу Microsoft-скую (dumpbin.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160), которая показывает всё что файл экспортирует если написать в командной строке адрес самой программы и к ней (после пробела) опцию "/exports". Microsoft говорит что она ещё многое что может сделать с этими файлами, там функций у неё много, на ссылке выше их можно посмотреть в руководстве(руководство переводится как "reference"). Таким образом с помощью этой программы и её опции "/exports" можно узнать правильные имена процедур в ней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам. Оказывается просто надо было все функции объявлять с подчёркиванием "`_`" в начале имени функции и "собакой" "`@`" на конце имени функции после которой указываются количество байт занимаемых параметрами процедуры.

Вот исправленный код объявления их внешними:

```
extern      _LoadLibraryA@4:near
extern      _GetProcAddress@8:near
extern      _FreeLibrary@4:near
extern      _ExitProcess@4:near
```

И при использовании (например через "`call`") тоже надо прописывать их так. Проверял по другому - не работает - писать нужно только так (Windows API-ские функции только, а свои можно хоть как (но надо ли "`@`" в своих функциях использовать не знаю)):

```
call    _LoadLibraryA@4
```

А в 64-битной программе эти функции по другому вызываются, без подчёркивания "`_`" и без указания собаки "`@`" и без указания байт параметров после неё.

```
call    LoadLibraryA
```

**Но** при передаче в функцию "`GetProcAddress`" имени функции которую нужно взять из DLL, нужно писать просто имя функции без этих символов.

Только осталась проблема что файл "`.exe`" сассемблировался не в нужную папку и теперь либо он не сассемблировался, либо его искать надо, но это уже другая тема, не этого вопроса, а сам вопрос решён.
**[Решил]** Оказывается надо прописать сначала в командной строке путь к папке в которой должен появится файл с помощью "`cd`", например " `cd "Путь к файлу"` "

И, кстати, только что узнал что нужно использовать процедуры с "`A`" символом на конце, а не "`W`", если используешь кавычки `' '` или `" "` для вписывания символов в память, иначе будешь получать иероглифы. Но процедуры с "`A`" символом на конце используются для работы с массивами символов как с 8-битными символами из кодировки ASCII, а процедуры с "`W`" символом на конце для работы с массивами символов как с 16-битной кодировкой Unicode (которая вроде UTF-16 называется, не помню точно)

Comment: Объявлять по образцу `_Name@x` необходимо функции stdcall на 32-битной платформе, как того требует ABI.

Comment: @user7860670, я об этом и сказал. Что на 32-битной платформе таким образом, а на 64-битной платформе просто имя. И кстати не все функции, использующие соглашение stdcall, именуются именно таким образом. В 64-битных библиотеках Windows API-ских функций эти функции указаны без такого правила именования, а просто их имя

Comment: @user7860670, Я тебе даже больше скажу - в само́й DLL "kernel32.dll" моей 64-битной операционной системы Windows 7 почти все процедуры называются без добавления к ним всяких небуквенных символов. Лишь к некоторым добавляют и то, просто подчеркивания, то есть явно по другой причине, и не таким же образом как для 32-битных библиотек. С помощью dumpbin.exe можно проверить (которую я упомянул в ответе на комментарий к главному вопросу)

Comment: На 64 битной платформе нет соглашения stdcall, только одно универсальное, соответственно нет необходимости декорировать функции.

Comment: @user7860670, Подожди, то есть получается что на 64-битной Windows параметры функции передаются не в стэк задом наперёд, а по-другому? И с очисткой стэка тоже по-другому? Или используется соглашение stdcall но неявно и без огласки?

Comment: Параметры не передаются задом наперед ни в 32 битных cdecl, stdcall, ни в 64 битном.

Comment: @user7860670, В интернете говорят другое, что в этом соглашении параметры передаются не как мы привыкли в C-подобных языках (слева первый параметр, и направо идут следующие), а наоборот (справа-налево, то есть тот который раньше был слева и первым - теперь последний, а тот который был раньше справа теперь первым передаётся): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соглашение_о_вызове#stdcall_или_winapi

Comment: По ссылке написано наоборот, что параметры передаются так же, как и в C-подобных языках (cdecl). Разница в первую очередь кто выполняет очистку стека

Comment: @user7860670, Я забыл упомянуть, что я имел ввиду передачу параметров программистом (вписывая параметры слева первым, направо - следующие), а не компиляторами. Потому что компиляторы-то да, преобразуют очерёдность твоих параметров так как прописано в их стандарте или смотря какое ты им указал соглашение. Поэтому здесь, когда я говорил "как в C-подобных языках", я имел ввиду то как вручную программист вписывает их; вдруг мало-ли какие-нибудь вертикальные или перевернутые(справа-налево) языки программирования существуют, в которых программистам придется писать по-другому