# Ассемблер MASM (64-битный) не распознаёт точку входа и выдаёт ошибку

Tags: windows, ассемблер, masm, x86-64, x86

Изучаю ассемблер для семейства архитектур процессоров x86 (32-битных и 64-битных) на Windows. Не сказать что совсем прям новичок, но наверное не все знаю, по крайней мере про синтаксис ассемблера MASM, как видимо. Использую ассемблер MASM (для 64-битных программ) находящийся в папках, принадлежащих Visual Studio:
"`..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\ml64.exe`"
Установлен Visual Studio 2019 года, из его папки и использую ассемблер MASM. У меня самого́ Windows 7

Я сделал мою программу для 32-битной системы, она нормально ассемблировалась MASM-ом для 32 битных программ и работала. Затем перевел её код под 64-битную архитектуру (а изменений там в коде необходимо мало). Но, при ассемблировании её MASM-ом для 64-битных программ, MASM выдавал сообщение об ошибке, что якобы есть какой-то нерешённый символ "`StartOfProgram`". Вот что в консоли:

```
C:\Assembler>cd "C:\Assembler"

C:\Assembler>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\ml64.exe" "C:\Assembler\Main.asm" /link /subsystem:windows /entry:StartOfProgram
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.29.30138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: C:\Assembler\Main.asm
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:Main.exe
Main.obj
/subsystem:windows
/entry:StartOfProgram
LINK : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ StartOfProgram.
Main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

Где-то 2 недели или месяц провозился в поисках решения этой ошибки, но не нашёл

Вообще, раньше он выдавал сообщение об ошибке, что якобы есть какой-то неразрешённый символ "`WinMainCRTStartup`", но недавно вроде понял, что это он такую точку входа сделал из-за того что я явно не указал точку входа в консоли (через команду "`/entry:`", которая есть в консоли сверху), но проблема про "`неразрешенный внешний символ`" осталась, даже несмотря на то что я установил точку входа там где мне надо (то есть, на "`StartOfProgram`")

---

Вот код моей 64-битной версии программы которая просто должна выводить "Hello world" во всплывающем окне:

```
option  casemap:none    ; Насколько я понял, функции из Windows API без чувствительности к регистру не работают

; **** Импорт того что нужно ****

includelib  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib"   ; Загружаю главную статическую библиотеку для использования основных Windows API-ских функций

extern      LoadLibraryA:near    ; Загружаю из статических библиотек используемые в этой программе функции
extern      GetProcAddress:near
extern      FreeLibrary:near
extern      ExitProcess:near

; **** Объявление сегмента памяти ****

.data

        text                    db  'Hello world', 0            ; Текст в "Text Box"-овском окне
        header                  db  'Title of hello world', 0   ; Заголовок "Text Box"-овского окна

        nameOfDLL               db  'user32.dll', 0
        nameOfProcedureOfDLL    db  'MessageBoxA', 0

        handlerToModule         dd  0                   ; Возвращаемый Windows-овскими функциями handler везде имеет размер 32 бита, и в 32-битных программах, и в 64-битных
        addressOfProcedureOfDLL dq  0                   ; В 64-битной операционной системе адреса 64-битные, поэтому размер области памяти на которую указывает эта метка - quad word (dq) (четверное слово) (то есть 64 бита)

.code

; **** Точка входа в программу ****

StartOfProgram:                 ; Ассемблер MASM почему-то рекомендует ставить знак "_" перед меткой точки входа в программу, если она 32-битная. Поэтому здесь, в 64-битной, наконец-то не ставлю

        mov     rcx, offset nameOfDLL
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    LoadLibraryA
        add     rsp, 40
        
        mov     qword ptr handlerToModule, rax

        mov     rcx, rax                ; В регистре осталось возвращаемое значение после LoadLibraryA, а регистры быстрее чем оперативная память, значит использовать регистр
        mov     rdx, offset nameOfProcedureOfDLL
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    GetProcAddress
        add     rsp, 40

        mov     addressOfProcedureOfDLL, rax
        
        mov     rcx, 0
        mov     rdx, offset text
        mov     r8, offset header
        mov     r9, 0
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    addressOfProcedureOfDLL         ; Поставил адрес, а не rax (в rax всё ещё остался этот адрес), потому что компьютер сразу перейдёт по адресу, вместо того чтобы сначала читать этот адрес с rax
        add     rsp, 40
        
        mov     rcx, offset handlerToModule
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    FreeLibrary
        add     rsp, 40

        mov     rcx, 0
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    ExitProcess
        add     rsp, 40

end
```

Вот код моей 32-битной версии этой программы (которая нормально ассемблировалась и работала):

```
.386    ; Указывается процессор с минимальным набором функций (так как новые процессоры Intel (в семействе архитектур "x86") совместимы (пока что) с инструкциями старых процессоров Intel того же семейства архитектур)

option  casemap:none    ; Насколько я понял, функции из Windows API без чувствительности к регистру не работают

; **** Импорт того что нужно ****

includelib  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib"   ; Загружаю главную статическую библиотеку без которой (насколько я понял) не заработает ни одна Windows-программа (то есть неконсольная)
;includelib  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86\User32.lib"

extern      _LoadLibraryA@4:near    ; Загружаю из статических библиотек используемые в этой программе функции
extern      _GetProcAddress@8:near  ; ^
extern      _FreeLibrary@4:near     ; ^
extern      _ExitProcess@4:near     ; ^

.model flat

; **** Объявление сегмента памяти ****

.data

        text                    db  'Hello world', 0            ; Текст в "Text Box"-овском окне
        header                  db  'Title of hello world', 0   ; Заголовок "Text Box"-овского окна

        nameOfDLL               db  'user32.dll', 0
        nameOfProcedureOfDLL    db  'MessageBoxA', 0

        handlerToModule         dd  0
        addressOfProcedureOfDLL dd  0

.code

; **** Точка входа в программу ****

_StartOfProgram:    ; Ассемблер MASM почему-то рекомендует ставить знак "_" перед меткой точки входа в программу, если она 32-битная

        push    offset nameOfDLL
        call    _LoadLibraryA@4                 ; Динамически подключаю DLL чтобы потом взять из неё функцию
        
        mov     handlerToModule, eax
        
        push    offset nameOfProcedureOfDLL
        push    eax                             ; Функции для 32-битных программ из Windows API используют соглашение stdcall. stdcall - это соглашение о передаче параметров функции в стэк задом наперёд, поэтому eax последним. В eax пока-что содержится Windows-овский адрес DLL (Microsoft называют его "handler"-ом) (после недавнего вызова функции LoadLibraryA), поэтому лучше регистр использовать, процессор быстрее работает с регистрами
        call    _GetProcAddress@8
        
        mov     addressOfProcedureOfDLL, eax    ; Сохраняю адрес процедуры, который взял из GetProcAdress
        
        push    0
        push    offset header
        push    offset text
        push    0
        call    addressOfProcedureOfDLL
        
        push    handlerToModule
        call    _FreeLibrary@4

        push    0
        call    _ExitProcess@4

end _StartOfProgram
```

И вот какой результат выдавала 32-битная версия программы:
[image: Результат работы 32-битной версии программы]

Comment: А после end имя метки писать не надо?

Comment: @Jack Katch, В 32-битных программах на конце директивы "end" нужно писать точку входа, иначе нужно писать её в командной строке через команду "/entry:". Но я пробовал через командную строку и чё-то он не понимал из каких символов она состоит и добавлял какие-то символы подчёркивания "_", поэтому не рекомендую использовать команду "/entry:" в командной строке при ассемблировании 32-битных программ. А вот в 64-битных программах MASM почему-то запрещает использовать конец директивы "end" для обозначения точки входа. В нём только вручную через командную строку командой "/entry:" она задаётся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Есть два варианта её решения: один как сказал(а) @user7860670 - через директивы "[`proc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proc?view=msvc-170)" и "[`endp`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/endp?view=msvc-170)", другой, о котором я узнал, - через директиву "[`public`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/public-masm?view=msvc-170)"

---

Я предпочитаю второй вариант решения - через директиву "`public`" - ,так как считаю что он более близок к низкоуровневому программированию. В этом втором варианте мне нужно было сделать свою метку публичной в моей программе с помощью директивы "`public`", а затем написать имя метки, для того чтобы она стала доступной для внешних программ. Ассемблер MASM, видимо, выдавал ошибку из-за того что не видел её доступной извне и поэтому не считал правильным назначать её точкой входа, хотя сам мог догадаться что если я указываю её точкой входа, значит она доступна для перехода на неё извне. Видимо, разработчики MASM-а не сделали это.
Вот пример использования этой директивы в моей программе:
`public StartOfProgram`
Причём, я заметил что эту директиву я могу ставить в любом месте своей программы

А вариант решения через директивы "`proc`" и "`endp`" делается установкой имени метки перед этими директивами (как написано в документации от Microsoft) и установкой начала ("`proc`") и конца ("`endp`") этой директивной процедуры.
Пример, как и показал(а) @user7860670:

```
StartOfProgram proc     ; - Начало директивной процедуры

; ... здесь может быть сам код внутри этой директивной процедуры

StartOfProgram endp     ; - Конец директивной процедуры
```

Видимо в каких-то случаях ассемблер MASM понимает что метка точки входа публична, а в каких-то не понимает, хоть и должен понимать что метка точки входа публична "[по определению](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_578&layout=item)", по смыслу, и логике

Answer (score 1):

Процедуры, включая точку входа, следует обозначать блоками `proc`/ `endp`

```
StartOfProgram proc
...
StartOfProgram endp

end
```

Имя с глобальным блоком, как и указание точки входа после `end` - это все вроде как атавизмы. Так что всегда используйте `proc`/ `endp` и `/entry:`.

А про необходимость `_` в имени функции вроде как уже выяснили в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1400589/%d0%90%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-masm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-windows-api-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba).

Comment: `Процедуры, включая точку входа, следует обозначать блоками proc/ endp` - откуда такое требование?   По идее это никак не должно влиять на работоспособность программы, это просто синтаксический сахар по сути.

Comment: @insolor Наоборот, синтаксический сахар - это указание названия метки после `end`, превращающее метку в полноценную процедуру. Без этого и 32 битный вариант бы не собирался, ругаясь на отсутствие `_StartOfProgram` при линковке. Также директива `proc`, помимо собственно создания процедуры, еще позволяет генерировать к ней блоки с данными для .pdata и раскрутки стека, что вообще-то следует делать в 64 битном варианте.

Comment: @user7860670, Вот именно, что "`proc`" и "`endp`" это макрос или что-то типо того. Программа спокойно могла начинаться с моей метки точки входа, а всякие нужные для функции данные в стэке и всё-такое я бы сделал сам. Может я в какой-то момент не захочу загружать стэк и очищать его так как принято MASM-ом, может я захочу по-своему управлять стэком? И так далее. Я в ассемблер не для того пришел чтобы программировать опять на тех же высокоуровневых макросах, скрывающих реализацию, или не дающих её изменить.

Comment: @user7860670, есть какой-то способ задать точку входа начиная с моей метки а не через высокоуровневые макросы "proc" и "endp"?

Comment: @Developer Нет `proc` и `endp` - это не макросы, а директивы. Метка в принципе не может выступать в качестве точки входа, так как метки не доступны для линковки.

Comment: @user7860670, То есть "`proc`" и "`endp`" не трогают стэк и всё остальное в коде а просто указывают адрес части кода?

Comment: @user7860670, И кстати, в 32-битной версии программы метка была доступна для линковки (иначе программа бы не ассемблировалась), так что это ты скорее всего ошибся

Comment: @Developer Да, `proc` и `endp` не трогают стек. Нет, метки не доступны для линковки, 32 битном варианте `_StartOfProgram` стало доступным для линковки, так как оно было указано в качестве точки входа после `end`. 32 битный вариант тоже следует переделать на использование `proc` и `endp`.

Comment: То есть в MASM для 32-битных программ директива end [метка] делала АБСОЛЮТНО то же что и "`proc`" и "`endp`"?

Comment: @Developer Ну в общем да.

Comment: @user7860670, Ты не знаешь литературу или другой доверяемый источник в котором это говорят? Потому что во многой литературе по MASM используют ассемблер с макросами и там от ассемблера настоящего мало чего остается и сами макросы там подробно не объясняют. Если информации нету то есть способ как это проверить? Потому что если внезапно окажется что эти директивы имеют побочное действие то в итоге моя программа будет иметь код которого я не вписывал и будут проблемы

Comment: @Developer MASM расшифровывается как Microsoft Macro Assembler. Соответственно использование макросов вместо копипасты простыни из ассемблерных команд в нем является прерогативой. Есть официальная документация https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=msvc-170

Comment: @user7860670, Документацию-то я смотрел. Она как и обычно оказалась ужасной для понимания, лишь как справочник. Тем не менее MASM называется ассемблером, а значит должен поддерживать низкоуровневое программирование, иначе должен называться полу-низкоуровневым ассемблером. Я конечно понимаю что они могут наплевать на название, но шанс-то есть что он поддерживает истинную низкоуровневость, поэтому хочу узнать как свою точку входа объявить без побочного кода который мне потом устроит проблемы

Comment: @user7860670, Чтобы не было типо как в `C++`: создаёшь просто консольную программку с выводом надписи "`Hello world`", а он тебе пол-гига библиотек понаприсоединяет, и потом твой код мало того что много весит, так ещё и имеет кучу проблем с несовместимостью этих библиотек с твоими процедурами/кодом/другими библиотеками

Comment: @Developer У вас совершенно превратные представления о низкоуровневой. Если вы видите простыню из ассемблера, то это еще не значит, что этот код низкоуровневый, и наоборот, если вы видите ассемблерные макросы и интринсики, то это не значит, что код не низкоуровневый. *"как в C++: создаёшь просто консольную программку с выводом надписи "Hello world", а он тебе пол-гига библиотек понаприсоединяет, и потом твой код мало того что много весит"* - ничего такого в C++ нет, а если вы вздумаете реализовать этот же функционал самостоятельно, то скорее всего результат получится намного тяжелее, чем в С++

Comment: @user7860670, Низкоуровневый язык это как минимум когда у тебя доступ ко всем инструментам ассемблера, кроме привилегированных операционной системой. Если нету возможности свободно использовать инструменты ассемблера (например метку) в какой-то ситуации, из-за того что они заменяются *обязательным* макросом/директивой и т.д., когда чисто технически можно сделать тот же результат, но без этой директивы и лишнего кода, то это уже не полноценное низкоуровневое программирование, а неправильное проектирование приложения-ассемблера, а именно его синтаксиса. Что, видимо, и сделали Microsoft с MASM-ом

Comment: @user7860670 "_ничего такого в C++ нет_" - Когда я создавал своё приложение на C++, то оно на жёстком диске весило то ли 1 МиБ, то ли 3 МиБ, а на ассемблере еле-еле 3 КиБ. В любом случае, Visual Studio пытается добавить туда код и библиотеки которые ты не подключал. И из-за этого многие программисты вынужденные в своей ситуации уменьшить вес своего приложения либо пытаются найти более лёгкую версию компилятора среди старых версий либо идут писать программу на ассемблере так как и в настройках компилятора фиг разберёшься из-за плохой документации и отсутствия нужных настроек в нужном количестве

Comment: Так что вопрос "создают ли "`proc`" и "`endp`" побочный код или являются просто такими же метками" или "как обойтись без "`proc`" и "`endp`" для создания точки входа" всё ещё открыт, важен, и актуален